# What does ":" mean in $PATH?

Tags: unix, path

This image shows the result when I put `echo $PATH`, and I wondering what the colon (:) represents. Is it a new directory?

[image]

Comment: for the meaning of ":" (colon) see here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311339/why-was-colon-chosen-as-path-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH is a string that can be split into multiple strings by the `:` delimiter. This is common on environment variables. On Windows it would be `;`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.